# Google Apps Script Google Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, contacts, google-contacts-api

I would like to list the Google contacts in my web app. I have 270 contacts in one of my group which takes 50 seconds to load all contacts using ContactsApp.getContacts(). Is there any way in Google apps script to fetch few contacts so that I can do pagination.

thanks in advance 
durga

Answer (score 2):

Well, contacts retrieving is quite slow for big datasets, but if you saying that you need contact from certain group - then maybe you are in luck, cause usually retrieving by group is much faster.
Try something like:

```
var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("GroupName");
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not perfect but I have seen that Spreadsheet is much faster.
1. Write a script to load contacts and save it in a [Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheet.google.com) using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app). Obviously, you can't save [contact objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact) in it. You would save strings that you need to display in your app. And create a trigger that updates this Spreadsheet every hour (or any interval that suites your need).
2. Now have your app talk to Spreadsheet which is displaying contacts rather than contacts.

I recommend to do a small test of reading values from Spreadsheet and see how fast is it. And if it is quick enough for you, build the app for syncing contacts with spreadsheet.

Comment: This presupposes the OP wants to abandon Google Contacts for using a spreadsheet solution…?

Comment: Contacts and calendar take more time to fetch 50 records than 50 rows in a Spreadsheet. My solution is just a work around to fetch information faster.
OP may want to stick with contact application because it may be used in many different ways in their whole solution and app script may be just a small part of it.